# Python thread not starting.

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocess

I am having issues with my `halt_listener` thread. I can start `import_1` but it will not spawn a `halt_listener` thread. I am patterning this after known good code, the only difference was in the last iteration the halt_listener got fed a pipe instead of a queue.

```
class test_imports:#Test classes remove 
      alive = {'import_1': True, 'import_2': True};

      def halt_listener(self, control_Queue, thread_Name, kill_command):
          while True:
              print ("Checking queue for kill")
              isAlive = control_queue.get()
              print ("isAlive", isAlive)
              if isAlive == kill_command:
                 print ("kill listener triggered")
                 self.alive[thread_Name] = False;
                 return

      def import_1(self, control_Queue, thread_Number):
          print ("Import_1 number %d started") % thread_Number
          t = Thread(target=test_imports.halt_listener, args=(control_Queue, 'import_1', 't1kill'))
          count = 0 
          global alive 
          run = test_imports.alive['import_1'];
          while run:
                print ("Thread type 1 number %d run count %d") % (thread_Number, count)
                count = count + 1
                print ("Test Import_1 ", run)
                run = self.alive['import_1'];
          print ("Killing thread type 1 number %d") % thread_Number 



      def import_2(self, control_queue, thread_number):
          print ("Import_2 number %d started") % thread_number
          count = 1
          while True:
                alive = control_queue.get()                   
                count = count + 1
                if alive == 't2kill':
                   print ("Killing thread type 2 number %d") % thread_number
                   return 
                else:
                     print ("Thread type 2 number %d run count %d") % (thread_number, count)
```

Anyone have any pointers to where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never call `t.start()` to actually start the thread.

Comment: Duh Durp!Heads up gentlemen that code is still throwing type errors but she is right that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

everything is okay, you just have to add t.start() to start your thread

```
t = Thread(target=test_imports.halt_listener, args=(control_Queue, 'import_1', 't1kill'))
t.start()
```